# arithmetic expression in Prolog

Tags: prolog, dcg

I am given a context-free grammar that defines what a valid arithmetic expression is in the given situation. And the question is to write it in haskell and Prolog. Here is the CFG.

```
Expr ::= lit(i)
| add(Expr, Expr)
| sub(Expr, Expr)
```

In Haskell it is fairly simple. I just use a data type, call it Expr and off I go. Here's what I wrote:

```
data Expr = Lit Integer |
            Add Expr Expr |
            Sub Expr Expr
```

But I am fairly stuck about writing it in Prolog. Furthermore, running expr(E), where E is an arithmetic expression, should evaluate to true if it really is an expression that is valid by the definition of the CFG. So far, I wrote this, but I don't think it is correct. So help me figure it out.

```
expr(lit(i), i).
expr(add(expr(), expr()), Res).
expr(sub(expr(), expr()), Res).
```

Comment: This is **not** a CFG! Where are the terminal symbols?

Comment: Let's say it's a NON-formal, symbolic CFG, if it matters at all.

Comment: The terminal symbol shout be i in lit(i).

Comment: That is not a CFG. And what about add?

Comment: I know what you mean, but this is how the question was phrased. So there's not much I can do about it. How else do you propose we call that structure?

Comment: Please reread my first comment: You do not state any terminal symbols, so it is not clear what this should mean. How should add look like?

Comment: for example we might want to construct an expression for adding 2 and 3. Then we'd say: expr( add( lit(2), lit(3) ) ). And this would be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're not required to *evaluate* the expression, the code could be

```
expr(lit(_)).
expr(add(E1,E2)) :- expr(E1), expr(E2).
expr(sub(E1,E2)) :- expr(E1), expr(E2).
```